# async-await issue in EF 6

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, async-await, entity-framework-6

I'm trying async-await programming with entity-framework 6 (code first) + WPF and I can't see why the UI still freezes after I made the code asynchronous.
Here is what I'm doing from the very first line:

first there is an event handler responding to a click button:

```
private async void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  if (await this._service.Authenticate(username.Text, password.Password) != null)
    this.Close();
}
```

Then I have the Authenticate method in my service layer:

```
public async Task<User> Authenticate(string username, string password) {
  CurrentUser = await this._context.GetUserAsync(username.ToLower().Trim(), password.EncryptPassword());
  return CurrentUser;
}
```

and at the end is the EF code in the context:

```
public async Task<User> GetUserAsync(string username, string password) {
  return await this.People.AsNoTracking().OfType<User>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Username == username && u.Password == password);
}
```

**Update:** After some tracing the cause of UI freezing turned out to be the initialization process. UI thread blocks until the EF context is initialized and once that is done the actual querying/saving process is performed asynchronously.

**Update** Debug output after the call on Task.Yield() at the beginning of the click handler:

```
53:36:378 Calling Task.Yield
53:36:399 Called Task.Yield
53:36:400 awaiting for AuthenticateAsync
53:36:403 awaiting for GetUserAsync
'MyApp.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\SkyDrive\Works\MyApp\MyApp.UI.WPF.Shell\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll'
'MyApp.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-MyApp.Model.Domain.People'
'MyApp.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-MyApp.Model.Domain.Security'
53:39:965 Out of GetUserAsync
53:39:968 out of AuthenticateAsync
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1e98) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x17d4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x175c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x220) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1dc8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1af8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: As far as i know is EF 6.0 not released yet and so the Task-based async support not fully implemented.

Comment: Also depends whether you underlying provider supports it. If not, it falls back to blocking.

Comment: Unrelated, but can you use OfType<User>() in that GetUserAsync?

Comment: How bad is the context initialization in terms of UI freeze? Is this something you can fix by forcing initialization at app startup? (It should only be slow once per app domain.)

Comment: Well it's a modular app. 7 modules each with its own domain. I think it takes about 8 seconds for each domain. I'd call that bad event at the startup.

Comment: @JamesManning Why didn't I do that? Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Vahid - when you say the blocking is during the initialization process, is that happening in the code you're showing?  IOW, is that happening in GetUserAsync when FirstOrDefaultAsync is called?  If not, what's the stack look like during the initialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods marked 'async' are still synchronous up until the point when the first 'await' happens.  Because of that, if any of what happens in that initial code takes too long (200ms or more I think is the guideline for WinRT, which seems reasonable), then you may want to force the code to return faster by inserting an await earlier.

For instance, in your LoginButton_Click, you can insert a first line of 'await [Task.Yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield.aspx)()' which will allow the call to return back to the UI thread faster.

Now, with that change alone, the methods will all still run on the UI thread due to the async/await behavior.  I still like making that change first because in many cases it's what the user actually expects is happening (the 'async' modifier being kind of confusing in that regard), and it's something you can do at the start of a handler without having to mess with things further down the stack.

The next step we can do if the above is insufficient (like the context initialization is taking too long, still happens on the UI thread, and still freezes the UI, just at a slightly different point in time) is taking those parts that don't need to happen on the UI thread and let await know that they can be processed on any thread, not just the UI thread.  This is generally a good practice anyway for responsiveness, even in scenarios where the code currently runs 'fast enough' to not be a noticeable problem.

For that, we use add [ConfigureAwait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait.aspx)(false) to the Task.

- GetUserAsync method should add it ("chain" it) after the FirstOrDefaultAsync call

  - alternatively, and IMHO slightly cleaner, is to just get rid of the async/await keywords in the GetUserAsync method and just return the task you get back from FirstOrDefaultAsync.  The async/await isn't really 'buying' you anything in this method as-is, IMHO :)
- in Authenticate, you should likely add it after the GetUserAsync call

  - the one potential 'gotcha' here that I'm not sure about is if the CurrentUser is data-bound into the UI.  Since it's a member of the _service, I'm guessing it's not, but even if it is, I *think* that WPF is fine with data-bound items being updated on non-UI threads and it deals with marshaling the changes back to the UI (dispatcher?) thread.  This is different than frameworks like Silverlight where updating a property on a non-UI that's data-bound into the UI will cause the same cross-thread failure as if you had manually updated the target control.  If I'm wrong about this, and 1) the CurrentUser is data-bound into your UI *and* 2) that data-bound update on a non-UI thread causes a runtime exception, then avoid the ConfigureAwait(false) addition in this method.  Sorry for the length of this, just trying to relate what I'm a little unsure of this particular modification. :)
- in LoginButton_Click, we should *NOT* add it, because the rest of the method (this.Close) needs to happen on the UI thread, and ConfigureAwait(false) here would break that

Once both of those changes are in, you'll both 1) be returning control back to the caller as quickly as you can (doing the least amount of code synchronous to the event handler) and 2) be doing work that doesn't need to be on the UI thread on other threads, which should hopefully mean your UI doesn't 'freeze' any more.

If it still freezes after those changes, you might just need to run it under a debugger, and when it freezes, break to see what the stack of the UI thread is to find the offending code. :)

Good luck!

Comment: Instead of Task.Yield which put me on track for a solution that really decouples the GUI thread I had to do this : await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false); to force a yield but to also continue on different thread. I cannot tell task.yield that it is supposed to use a different thread from now on. I cannot help wondering if there is a better way than basically a delay how arbitrary low it may be